# How to put linear gradient right after background image?

Tags: css

Is there a way to put an image as a background with cover size and then right after the image to put a gradient? It will create something like fading.
I tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```css
body { 
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('./images/bg.jpg') no-repeat, linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(23,26,25,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); 
}
```

Comment: Could you share/elaborate your desired output?

Comment: @0stone0 http://prntscr.com/uw3xj9 Something like this. You see how it starts with an image and then right after the image there is the gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cover is going to stretch your image to "cover" the background, so you'd never see the gradient anyway, which is also a background image.  You could set the gradient as the body's background then using a container DIV with the image background.

CSS:

```css
#container{
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/000/299/953/small/y2ok_2cif_180815.jpg') no-repeat;}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(23,26,25,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); 
}
```

Page:

```
<div id="container">

    // put page code in here like it was body

</div>
```